# How to parse a file into a list of string to use for auto-complete in a windows forms application in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sharpsvn

I am building an application in `C#` that has a textbox field. In this field, a user will write text and the text will autocomplete from a file found on a remote repository. I am using a library called SharpSVN and I am trying to find a method where I can fetch that file from the repository based on a certain path I provide, then parse the content into strings that will be added to the list in the autocomplete of the textbox mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1. Download the file text using the repository url. If you want the file at a specific revision, try entering in "?r=12345" as to get the file's appearance at a specific revision number:

   ```
   string fileText = new WebClient().DownloadFile("https://myrepo.com/myfile.txt", localFilename);
   ```
2. Or, you could also use SharpSVN, removing the revision options if you want the latest version:

   ```
   public string GetFileContentsAsString(long revisionNumber)
   {
       return new StreamReader(GetFileContents(revisionNumber)).ReadToEnd();
   }

   private MemoryStream GetFileContents(long revisionNumber)
   {
       SvnRevision rev = new SvnRevision(revisionNumber);
       MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

       using (SvnClient client = GetClient())
       {
           client.FileVersions(SvnTarget.FromUri(RemotePath), new SvnFileVersionsArgs() { Start = rev, End = rev }, (s, e) =>
           {
               e.WriteTo(stream);
           });
       }
       stream.Position = 0;

       return stream;
   }
   ```

When you have the file as a text string, you can use .NET's [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to split the text into a list of lines using the '\n' line-break character as the delimiter:

```
string[] fileAsLines = fileText.Split(new char[] {'\n'});
```